# Difference between PHP SQL Server Driver and SQLCMD when running queries

Tags: php, sql-server

Why is that the SQL Server PHP Driver has problms with long running queries?

Every time I have a query that takes a while to run, I get the following errors from sqlsrv_errors() in the below order:

> Shared Memory failure, Communication
>   Link Failure, Timeout failure

But if I try the same query with SQLCMD.exe it comes back fine. Does the PHP SQL Server Driver have somewhere that a no timeout can be set?

Whats the difference between running queries via SQLCMD and PHP Driver?

Thanks all for any help

Typical usage of the PHP Driver to run a query.

```
function already_exists(){

    $model_name = trim($_GET['name']);

    include('../includes/db-connect.php');

    $connectionInfo = array('Database' => $monitor_name);

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    $tsql = "SELECT model_name FROM slr WHERE model_name = '".$model_name."'";

    $queryResult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

    if($queryResult != false){

        $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($queryResult);

        if ($rows === true){

             return true;

        }else{

            return false;
        }

    }else{

           return false;         
    }

    sqlsrv_close($conn);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366/a-checklist-for-fixing-net-applications-to-sql-server-timeout-problems-and-impro

Comment: @vgv8 not a duplicate as that question isn't related to the PHP SQL Server Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLCMD has no query execution timeout by default. PHP does. I assume you're using `mssql_query`? If so, the default timeout for queries through this API is 60 seconds. You can override it by modifying the configuration property `mssql.timeout`.

See more on the configuration of the MSSQL driver in [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.configuration.php).

If you're not using mssql_query, can you give more details on exactly how you're querying SQL Server?

**Edit [based on comment]**
Are you using `sqlsrv_query` then? Looking [at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184(SQL.90).aspx) this should wait indefinately, however you can override it. How long is it waiting before it seems to timeout? You might want to time it and see if it's consistent. If not, can you provide a code snippet (edit your question) to show how you're using the driver.

If MSDTC is getting involved (and I don't know how you can ascertain this), then there's a 60-second timeout on that by default. This is configured in the Component Services administration tool and lives in a different place dependent on version of Windows.

Comment: I am using the PHP SQL Server Driver: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/php-driver.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your continued help Chris. I have updated my question with example usage. The time it waits is quite random and not consistent, I have tried it a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

> SQL Server 2005 limits the maximum
>   number of TDS packets to 65,536 per
>   connection (limit that was removed in
>   SQL Server 2008). As the default
>   PacketSize for the SQL Server Native
>   Client (ODBC layer) is 4K, the PHP
>   driver has a de-facto transfer limit
>   of 256MB per connection.  When
>   attempting to transfer more than
>   65,536 packets, the connection is
>   reset at TDS protocol level.
>   Therefore, you should make sure that
>   the BULK INSERT is not going to push
>   through more than 256 MB of data;
>   otherwise the only alternative is to
>   migrate your application to SQL Server
>   2008.

From MSDN Forums

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldriverforphp/thread/4a8d822f-83b5-4eac-a38c-6c963b386343

Comment: Will running a query and then waiting for a result for a long time count towards these packets being sent?

Comment: Only if the returned data is big enough, but looking at your updated example does not seem to be so much.

Comment: thank you for your help so far. The queries I am having trouble with don't usually return data if any! Mainly select and indexing queries. It would of made sense if the PHP Drivers query connection open time counted towards those packets as the queries I run, I expect to take about 30+ minutes.

Comment: If it's a maintenance low profile script you can try to reconnect before each query execution to prevent this kind of timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

PHP itself has several different timeout settings that you can control via `php.ini`.  The one that often causes problems like you're seeing is [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) (see also [`set_time_limit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)).  If these limits are exceeded, php will simply kill the process without regard for ongoing activities (like a running db query).

There is also a setting, [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), that does as its name suggests.  If the memory limit is exceeded, php just kills the process without warning.

good luck.